# Django cleaned_data.get('obj') method returns none

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-2.0

I'm doing a little password confirmation form in django. But Im confused as the `self.cleaned_data.get('confirm_password')` always returns none and hence my passwords never match to one another.

Heres the `clean` method in the `forms.py`

```
def clean_password(self):
    password = self.cleaned_data.get("password")
    confirm_password = self.cleaned_data.get("confirm_password")
    if password != confirm_password:
        print(password)
        print(confirm_password)
        raise forms.ValidationError(
        "Password and password confirmation does not match"
        )
    return password
```

`self.cleaned_data.get('password')` returns the typed password but the confirm_password doesnt.

In the `view.py` when I see the received data before cleaning, the confirm_password shows as it is

```
......................user = UserRegister(request.POST)
        print(request.POST.get('confirm_password'))

        if user.is_valid():
            print('valid')..........................
```

What could possibly be the reason for this??

Heres the form declaration part in `forms.py`

```
first_name = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.widgets.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'First Name'}))
last_name = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.widgets.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Last Name'}))
username = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.widgets.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Username'}))
email = forms.EmailField( required=True, widget=forms.widgets.EmailInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Email'}))
password =forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.widgets.PasswordInput())
confirm_password =forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.widgets.PasswordInput())

class Meta:
    model=User
    fields=['first_name','last_name','username','email','password','confirm_password']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`clean_fieldname` methods called in order of fields declaration, so at the moment `clean_password` is called `cleaned_data` does not contain `confirm_password`. You can perform this validation in `clean_confirm_password` method:

```
def clean_confirm_password(self):
    password = self.cleaned_data.get("password")
    confirm_password = self.cleaned_data.get("confirm_password")
    if password != confirm_password:
        print(password)
        print(confirm_password)
        raise forms.ValidationError(
        "Password and password confirmation does not match"
        )
    return password
```

or just use `clean` method for validation  that requires access to multiple form fields.

Comment: Thanks a ton. Cheers mate.

Answer (score 2):

The `clean_<fieldname>()` methods are called as the fields are being validated. You can't count on any other fields being in cleaned_data at that time except for the field you are working with. If you need to work with multiple fields override the form's clean() method.

Answer (score 1):

Since you do the validation between multiple fields you should override form's `clean`method.

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super().clean()
    password = self.cleaned_data.get("password")
    confirm_password = self.cleaned_data.get("confirm_password")
    if password != confirm_password:
        print(password)
        print(confirm_password)
        raise forms.ValidationError(
        "Password and password confirmation does not match"
        )
    return cleaned_data
```